# Superdry. 極度乾燥(しなさい)

Tags: etymology

How did this brand name [Superdry. 極度乾燥(しなさい)](http://www.superdry.com/) come about? Is there any deep consideration behind it? Are the customers having some thoughts?

Comment: It looks like a “translation” practice similar to [this](http://revealingerrors.com/translation_systems), but what is the point of asking this?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Since the brand seems popular, I do not think it was just a simple stupidity. But I was not sure.

Comment: @Flaw I am not saying it sucks. I take that as granted. I am wondering why such sucking expression is being popular. But it is true that it is probably not a useful question.

Comment: http://blog.goo.ne.jp/kennytata/e/448af50e48466dcbd862544e4f84659c　でも笑えます。。。

Comment: @Chocolateさん それ、僕も見ました。いいですよね。どんな意図なのか興味があったんですが、質問が閉じられるならそれでもいいです。ありがとう。

Comment: I thought that Superdry was a Japanese-owned company. But I was confusing [SuperGroup plc's Superdry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdry) with [Asahi Breweries' Super Dry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asahi_Super_Dry).

Comment: イギリス来てます^^ SuperDryの店あります。みんな結構着てます。値段はちょっと高めだと思います。意味は気にしないようです。機械翻訳だと知ってる人もいますが、知らない人もいます。着てる人に「え？この日本語、間違ってんの？」と驚かれました。日本に行って感銘を受けた人が作った会社だということはみんな知ってるようですが、ビールから付けた名前だとは知らないようです。

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in [this BBC documentary called "Secrets of the Superbrands"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZh1a-c3e_I#t=36m46s).

The owner of the [Cheltenham based British company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperGroup_plc) that developed the brand simply went to Japan, possibly as far back as 1985, was inspired by Japanese packaging, and used that to develop their graphic images.