# What's the first character in the phrase 「?度乾燥しなさい」?

Tags: kanji

A couple days ago I came across the following Japanese phrase:

> ?度乾燥しなさい

"?" represents a character I was unable to recognize. Attempts at drawing it on Google Android handwriting input yielded 樶, 橄, 裕, 榴, 欄. A few attempted decompositions I remember:

1. Tree radical, on its right the composition of upper part of 習, a mouth side by side with something and a horizontal line below;
2. Tree radical, 習 on the right;
3. Tree or origin radical, on the right a day on top of a ear and 又 or 文 - that gave 樶.

Any idea what that character may be?

PS Searching 度 with JEDict led me to 極度. Could that be it?

Comment: More context may make the puzzle easier. Where did you find the phrase?

Comment: Surely [googling the exact phrase you had (度乾燥しなさい)](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E5%BA%A6%E4%B9%BE%E7%87%A5%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%22&cad=h) would have led you to the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is 極【きょく】.

See also the (closed) question [Superdry. 極度乾燥(しなさい)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6434/superdry-%E6%A5%B5%E5%BA%A6%E4%B9%BE%E7%87%A5%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%95%E3%81%84) for the origins of this.

Comment: Also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperGroup). `kyokudo kansou` translates `superdry`, but what is the `shinasai` there for?

Comment: This Japanese is simply funny and broken. I doubt it's worth seriously analyzing this as a Japanese sentence.

Comment: I like this article: http://www.unmissablejapan.com/etcetera/superdry Wow, they don't sell water-resistant products?

Comment: @naruto is correct. If you want to write superdry in Japanese, it is much more appropriate to just say `スーパードライ`, just like the Asahi beer.

Comment: Note that 極度 is usually used in negative contexts, like *overly* （「極度の緊張で声が出ない」「極度に乾燥した気候のため草も生えない」） 極限【きょくげん】 nad 究極【きゅうきょく】 are the positive words which corresponds to *ultimate*, *maximum*, or whatever.